# Array add previous index value to next index Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

Here is my array:

```
array = [100.0, 10.0, 250.0, 360.0]
```

The final number is the total and works well with what I want, however, what I'm really looking for is this:

```
array = [100.0, 110.0, 360.0]
```

In more words I want the starting value to stay the same and then each additional value to be the sum of the value before + the next value...

Any help would be awesome. I started writing a for statement, but I dont know how to raise the index for each statement? I think its something like i++?

Thank you

Comment: [Edit] your question with your code. Show what you have tried. Explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a var `total` to keep track of the running total and use `map` to create a new array with each item replaced by total of it and the previous ones:

```
let array = [100.0, 10.0, 250.0]
var total = 0.0

let result = array.map { value -> Double in total += value; return total }
print(result)
```

> ```
> [100.0, 110.0, 360.0]
> ```

---

**Using a for loop:**

This accomplishes the same task using a `for` loop to build up the `result`:

```
let array = [100.0, 10.0, 250.0]
var result = [Double]()
var total = 0.0

for value in array {
    total += value
    result.append(total)
}

print(result)
```

> ```
> [100.0, 110.0, 360.0]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most straightforward way is by using a for loop.

```
let numbers = [100.0,10.0,250.0]

var sum = [Double]()

for number in numbers{
    sum.append((sum.last ?? 0.0) + number)
}    
// sum : [100.0, 110.0, 360.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a running sum:

```
let array = [100.0, 10.0, 250.0]
let runningSum = array.reduce([Double]()) { aggregate, element in
    aggregate + [aggregate.last ?? 0 + element]
}

print(runningSum)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't show how you add these values to the array so I can't give you a complete answer. Where you add the new value do:

```
array.append(array.last + newValue)
```

This adds a value to the array that is the last value + a new value. This does require the array to be ordered.

Edit: I cannot remember now if you can call .last when appending, if you can't you can get arround that doing:

```
let last = array.last
array.append(last + newValue)
```

Comment: Can someone explain why I got downvoted?

Comment: Hey thank you for the Answer. I upvoted you because I don't really understand why you got down voted, and some of these moderators are on a power trip... haha